# Loading Large data into SQL Server [BCP] using Python

Tags: python, sql-server

After scanning the very large daily event logs using regular expression, I have to load them into a SQL Server database. I am not allowed to create a temporary CSV file and then use the command line BCP to load them into the SQL Server database.

Using Python, is it possible to use BCP streaming to load data into SQL Server database? The reason I want to use BCP is to improve the speed of the insert into SQL Server database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The BCP API is only available using the ODBC call-level interface and the managed SqlClient .NET API using the SqlBulkCopy class.  I'm not aware of a Python extension that provides BCP API access.

You can insert many rows in a single transaction to improve performance.  This can be accomplished by batching individual insert statements or by passing multiple rows at once using an XML parameter (which also reduces round-trips).